# How can I recreate this type of displacement?

Tags: modifiers, displacement

I'm a blender novice and I'm looking to create this glitched out, distorted kind of displacement as seen on the model below, where the form almost inverts on itself in places. any advice on node setups would be much appreciated

[image]